# expression "get above/off your sofas"

Tags: expressions

Is the expression "get above your sofas" equivalent to "get off your sofas" or have they got different meanings?
PS: I was sitting on my sofa when I heard that...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you may have misheard the phrase, "Get up off your sofas," which is relatively common.

I have never heard, and couldn't find, "Get above your sofas."

Comment: Aaah, that's right!